# Ansible conditional based on stdout of result?

Tags: linux, ansible

How do I use the when statement based on the standard output of register: result?  If standard output exists I want somecommand to run if no standard output exists I want someothercommand to run.

```
- hosts: myhosts
  tasks:
  - name: echo hello
    command: echo hello
    register: result
  - command: somecommand {{ result.stdout }}
    when: result|success
  - command: someothercommand
    when: result|failed
```

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Try checking to see it if equals a blank string or not?

```
- hosts: myhosts
  tasks:
  - name: echo hello
    command: echo hello
    register: result
  - command: somecommand {{ result.stdout }}
    when: result.stdout != ""
  - command: someothercommand
    when: result.stdout == ""
```

Answer (score 29):

As of 2018, the recommended way to test if output is empty is just:

```
when: result.stdout | length > 0
```

That is the pythonic way of evaluating truth, null, empty strings, empty lists all evaluate as false.

Other older alternatives **not recommended** or even not working:

- `result.stdout != ""` would not pass ansible-lint check!
- `result.stdout | bool` will NOT work as most strings will evaluate as False, only cases where it would return true is if stdout happens to be one of the `true`, `yes`,... kind of strings.
- `result.stdout` used to work but now triggers:

> [DEPRECATION WARNING]: evaluating  as a bare variable, this
>   behaviour will go away and you might need to add |bool to the
>   expression in the future. Also see CONDITIONAL_BARE_VARS configuration
>   toggle.. This feature will be removed in version 2.12. Deprecation
>   warnings can be disabled by setting deprecation_warnings=False in
>   ansible.cfg.`

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. This seems problematic if `stdout` is not defined.

Comment: I'm curious why most strings would evaluate to false. In Python, almost every string evaluates to true.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59085721/871113) and address the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26142343/ansible-conditional-based-on-stdout-of-result#comment127595801_59085721) regarding potential problems if `stdout` isn't defined, the following `when` statement can be used to ensure `stdout` is defined before trying to check its length:

```
when: result.stdout is defined and result.stdout | length > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for something similar but it took a while to find the right Google keywords. In my case, I am checking whether Docker run succeeds without error but the problem is the command will run indefinitely.

So instead I'll wait for an arbitrary amount of time and see whether the stdout is correct and stderr is empty:

```yaml
- name: Start container to see it doesn't crash
  shell: timeout 10s /usr/src/app/start.sh
  register: docker_run
  failed_when: "'Listening on: 0.0.0.0:80' not in docker_run.stdout or docker_run.stderr == ''"
  async: 12
  poll: 6
```

Hope this helps someone.