# Ansible: How to test that a registered variable is not empty?

Tags: ansible, yaml

How can I test that stderr is non empty::

```
- name: Check script
  shell: . {{ venv_name }}/bin/activate && myscritp.py
  args:
    chdir: "{{ home }}"
  sudo_user: "{{ user }}"
  register: test_myscript

- debug: msg='myscritp is Ok'
  when: not test_myscript.stderr
```

So if there is no error I could read::

```
  TASK: [deploy | debug msg='critp is Ok] *******
  ok: [vagrant] => {
      "msg": "myscritp is Ok"
  }
```

In case the stderr is not empty a `FATAl` error occurs.

Comment: See: [Jinja2: Check If Variable – Empty | Exists | Defined | True](https://www.shellhacks.com/jinja2-check-if-variable-empty-exists-defined-true/).

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can check for empty string (when stderr is empty)

```
- name: Check script
  shell: . {{ venv_name }}/bin/activate && myscritp.py
  args:
    chdir: "{{ home }}"
  sudo_user: "{{ user }}"
  register: test_myscript

- debug: msg='myscritp is Ok'
  when: test_myscript.stderr == ""
```

If you want to check for fail:

```
- debug: msg='myscritp has error: {{test_myscript.stderr}}'
  when: test_myscript.stderr != ""
```

Also look at this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26142343/ansible-conditional-based-on-stdout-of-result)

Comment: Ansible Galaxy Syntax Score: reports "E602:  Don't compare to empty string".

Answer (score 97):

<sup>(ansible 2.9.6 ansible-lint 5.3.2)</sup>

See ansible-lint [rules](https://ansible-lint.readthedocs.io/rules/empty-string-compare/). The condition below results in error: *'`empty-string-compare: Don't compare to empty string`'*

```yaml
    when: test_myscript.stderr != ""
```

Correct syntax is

```yaml
    when: test_myscript.stderr | length > 0
```

Quoting from [source code](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-lint/blob/main/src/ansiblelint/rules/empty_string_compare.py#L23)

> *Use `when: var|length > 0` rather than `when: var != ""` (or '
> 'conversely `when: var|length == 0` rather than `when: var == ""`)*

---

Notes

1. Test empty bare variable e.g.

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "Empty string '{{ var }}' evaluates to False"
      when: not var
      vars:
        var: ''

    - debug:
        msg: "Empty list {{ var }} evaluates to False"
      when: not var
      vars:
        var: []
```

give

```yaml
  msg: Empty string '' evaluates to False
  msg: Empty list [] evaluates to False
```

2. But, testing non-empty bare variable string depends on [CONDITIONAL_BARE_VARS](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/reference_appendices/config.html#conditional-bare-vars). Setting `ANSIBLE_CONDITIONAL_BARE_VARS=false` the condition works fine but setting `ANSIBLE_CONDITIONAL_BARE_VARS=true` the condition will fail

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "String '{{ var }}' evaluates to True"
      when: var
      vars:
        var: 'abc'
```

gives

```yaml
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => 
  msg: |-
    The conditional check 'var' failed. The error was: error while 
    evaluating conditional (var): 'abc' is undefined
```

Explicit cast to Boolean prevents the error but evaluates to False i.e. will be always skipped (unless `var='True'`). When the filter `bool` is used the options `ANSIBLE_CONDITIONAL_BARE_VARS=true` and `ANSIBLE_CONDITIONAL_BARE_VARS=false` have no effect

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "String '{{ var }}' evaluates to True"
      when: var|bool
      vars:
        var: 'abc'
```

gives

```yaml
skipping: [localhost]
```

3. Quoting from [Porting guide 2.8 Bare variables in conditionals](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/porting_guides/porting_guide_2.8.html#bare-variables-in-conditionals)

```yaml
  - include_tasks: teardown.yml
    when: teardown

  - include_tasks: provision.yml
    when: not teardown
```

> *" based on a variable you define as a string (with quotation marks around it):"*

- In Ansible 2.7 and earlier, the two conditions above are evaluated as True and False respectively if teardown: 'true'
- In Ansible 2.7 and earlier, both conditions were evaluated as False if teardown: 'false'
- In Ansible 2.8 and later, you have the option of disabling conditional bare variables, so when: teardown always evaluates as True, and when: not teardown always evaluates as False when teardown is a non-empty string (including 'true' or 'false')

4. Quoting from [CONDITIONAL_BARE_VARS](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/reference_appendices/config.html#conditional-bare-vars)

> *Expect that this setting eventually will be deprecated after 2.12*

Comment: This did not work for me. For me this : `'{{ my_variable | length | int }} > 0'` worked. PS: It gives me the warning `[WARNING]: when statements should not include jinja2 templating delimiters such as {{ }} or {% %}.`

Comment: @Raj: It's not enough to say "This did not work for me". Post the details and prove it. Follow [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It's strange to propose wrong syntax instead.

Comment: @VladimirBotka I had a scenario where `when: foo == ''` and `when: foo != ''`was failing. Following your 'test bare variable' update worked for me. When I used `when: foo` and `when: not foo` I got the expected results. Great tip here.

Comment: I updated the answer with the current status. It's better to test the length instead of the implicit boolean. In 2.9.6, the evaluation of an empty string as a boolean works fine but the evaluation of a non-empty string depends on ANSIBLE_CONDITIONAL_BARE_VARS. It's a moving target. Test the length of the string to be on the safe side.

Answer (score 15):

```
when: myvar | default('', true) | trim != ''
```

I use `| trim != ''` to check if a variable has an empty value or not. I also  always add the `| default(..., true)` check to catch when `myvar` is undefined too.