# Ansible Task failing with when condition

Tags: ansible, jinja2, amazon-ecs

My Ansible Task is getting failed with false when condition ( Task should fail only if "when" condition is true)

My Playbook

```
    - name: 'Check if any task is existing'
      command: aws ecs list-tasks --cluster mycluster --query length(taskArns[*])
      register: ecs_tasks

    - name: 'Fail playbook if some task is already existing in cluster'
      fail:
        msg: "There is already an existing task in mycluster"
      when: ecs_tasks.stdout != 0

    - name: 'Create Ranger task'
      command: create ECS task
      register: ecs_task
```

Output

```
    "stderr": "", 
    "stderr_lines": [], 
    "stdout": "0", 
    "stdout_lines": [
        "0"
    ]
    }

    TASK [Fail playbook if some task is already existing in cluster] ***************
    task path: /home/somepath/Task.yml:35
    fatal: [127.0.0.1]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "msg": "There is already an existing task in mycluster"
    }

    PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
09:09:38  127.0.0.1                  : ok=5    changed=4    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Is it some issue with my when Condition format, because i have tried various conditions like >0 and >=1, but no luck as it is still failing for (No tasks exists in my ECS cluster) and also
AWS CLI Command returns

```
aws ecs list-tasks --cluster mycluster --query length(taskArns[*])
0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are comparing a `string` (in your registered output) to an `int` (in your when clause). You should change your `when` condition to:

```yaml
when: ecs_tasks.stdout != "0"
```

Moreover, you do not need a second task to verify for failure as you can easily use the `failed_when` condition on your first task:

```yaml
    - name: 'Check if any task is existing'
      command: aws ecs list-tasks --cluster mycluster --query length(taskArns[*])
      register: ecs_tasks
      failed_when: ecs_tasks.stdout != "0"
```

**Side notes**:

- It is usually a good practice to still check for the command return code if it is still meaningful so that you don't unnecessarily parse output that could be misinterpreted. In your case, I guess you can easily change your condition to (note that `rc` is an `int`):

  ```yaml
  failed_when: ecs_tasks.rc != 0 or ecs_tasks.stdout != "0"
  ```

  if your command has several return codes that can be considered as successful (e.g. `0` and `2`), you can change to

  ```yaml
  failed_when: ecs_tasks.rc not in [0,2] or ecs_tasks.stdout != "0"
  ```
- You could be tempted to cast your output comparison as `int` like:

  ```yaml
  ecs_tasks.stdout | int != 0
  ```

  This should work, but be aware that any string value in `sdtout` not parseable as an int will lead to `O`, e.g.:

  ```
  $ ansible localhost -m debug -a msg="{{ 'whatever' | int }}"
  localhost | SUCCESS => {
  "msg": "0"
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Either of below should work :

```
- name: 'Fail playbook if some task is already existing in cluster'
  fail:
    msg: "There is already an existing task in mycluster"
  when: ecs_tasks.stderr | length > 0
```

Or

```
- name: 'Fail playbook if some task is already existing in cluster'
  fail:
    msg: "There is already an existing task in mycluster"
  when: ecs_tasks.stderr != ""
```

Refer more here : [How to test that a registered variable is not empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36912726/how-to-test-that-a-registered-variable-is-not-empty)

Comment: OP does not want to check that registered var is empty but that it does not contain "0".