# echo message based on ansible stdout value

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-facts

Team,

Not sure why my message with echo is not getting printed. I want to print a text if command that ran before for stopping process was successful.

In my case am checking for apache2 process status. Basically, if stdout is empty it passed and if stderr exists it failed. I also referred this link but no luck..
`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26142343/ansible-conditional-based-on-stdout-of-result`

```
- name: stop apache2 process
  command: systemctl stop apache2
  ignore_errors: no
  changed_when: false
  register: service_apache2_status
  become: true
```

```
- debug:
    var: service_apache2_status.stdout
```

```
- name: Check if apache2 stopped
  command: echo "Successfully Stopped Apache2"
#  when: service_apache2_status.stdout == " "
  when: service_apache2_status.stdout | length == 0
```

Actual output:

```
TASK [diskcache_prerequisites : stop apache2 process] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [diskcache_prerequisites : debug] *************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
   "service_apache2_status.stdout": ""
}

TASK [diskcache_prerequisites : Check if apache2 stopped] ******************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]
```

expected output:

```
TASK [diskcache_prerequisites : Check if apache2 stopped] ******************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]
Successfully Stopped Apache2
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the "check if apache2 stopped" at all if you use the [`systemd` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/systemd_module.html) instead of trying to use `command:` to call `systemctl` by hand

As for your question: if you want to **see** output, that's what `- debug: msg="Successfully stopped Apache2"` is for; the `command:` module is not a general purpose debugging tool, it's for running *commands*

Comment: for 1: what is the difference  between service module and systemd module, both same?

for 2: can you clarify as i did not understand how is debug being printed? coz i don't see using when in there.

Comment: No, [`service:`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/service_module.html) is designed for the old `/etc/init.d` based services, which respond only to `start`, `stop` and sometimes `status`, and `systemd` is what its name implies

Comment: I find it suspicious that you didn't see output when using `debug:`, but feel free to [edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61379528/edit) and provide the output you are experiencing along with what you expected to see